# Ionic 2 ion-avatar not showing on the left side

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to create a card in my ionic 2 application, like this example from the  documentation:

[image]

So I wrote this:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of myItems">
        <ion-item id="card-header">  
            <ion-avatar item-start>
                <img src="image_url" >
            </ion-avatar>

            <h2>Person name</h2>
            <p>99/99/9999</p>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-card-content>
           My content
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

But what I'm getting is this:

[image]

As you can see the avatar is positioned on a full line, not on the same line as the person name and other line. Why my avatar icon is not beeing shown on the left side of the line?

Comment: code is working for me, please check whether you have applied any styles for your id <ion-item id="card-header">

Comment: I haven't. In fact, I've put this id after detecting the problem, trying to fix it with css. I actually solved the problem, but using display flex on the ion-label wich is generated inside the ion-item, but since the documentation claims the framework do it by default, I'd like to find a better solution.